# How to retrieve two numbers from DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following function in PySpark.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

def get_num(self, spark, id):

    df = spark \
        .read \
        .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
        .load("myindex") \
        .filter(func.col("id") == id) \
        .groupBy("id") \
        .agg(
                func.count(func.lit(1)).alias("number_occurrences_today"),
                func.countDistinct("host_id").alias("number_hosts")
            )
```

If `df` is None, the function should return 0, 0. Otherwise, it should return the value of `number_occurrences_today` and `number_hosts` for `id`.

How can I do it?

This is what I tried so far:

```
    if (df is None):
        return 0, 0
    else:
        return df["number_occurrences_today"], df["number_hosts"]
```

Comment: @user6910411: What should I do to get two numbers? `collect()[0]` and `collect()[1]`  ?

Comment: Didn't find the answer in the threads.